# espaçamentos entre as li - CSS

Tags: css

Estou tentando dar um espaçamento no meu menu para ele ficar centralizado com o conteudo... o conteudo tem `width:80%;` ...

[SITE](http://www.planow.com.br/nobre)

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
```

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav cl-effect-1">
  <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="empresa.php">EMPRESA</a></li>
  <li><a href="servicos.php">SERVIÇOS</a></li>
  <li><a href="galeria.php">FOTOS</a></li>  
  <li class="imagem-menu"><a href="index.php"><img src="img/logo.png"></a></li>          
  <li><a href="eventos.php">NOSSOS EVENTOS</a></li>               
  <li><a href="agenda.php">AGENDA</a></li>
  <li><a href="contato.php">CONTATO</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
nav a{
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
}

nav.navbar.navbar-default {
background: transparent;
border: none;
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

li img {
margin: -110px 0 0 0;
width: 60%;
}

ul.nav.navbar-nav.cl-effect-1 {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
float: none;
display: table;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 110px;
/* width: 80%; */
}

ul.nav.navbar-nav.cl-effect-1 li a {
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Century Gothic;
}

nav a:hover{
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Coloca ao menos o código do teu menu...

Comment: Toda pergunta é a mesma coisa, nunca coloca o código, espera alguém pedir pra colocar. Acredito que isso seja o básico para qualquer pessoa poder te ajudar!

Comment: vou por...um momento

Comment: @CesarMiguel ta la

Comment: O menu está centralizado, o conteúdo é que não...

Comment: Centraliza o `<li>`, não o `<ul>`, ou deixa o `<li>` do tamanho do `<ul>`.

Comment: to quase conseguindo, pera ae que ja vo coloca no ar

Comment: @Patrick da olha olhada, [site](http://www.planow.com.br/nobre) o lance é o font-sizem, porem eu não posso aumentar a fonte, precisava aumentar o espaço entre as li sem que ocorra a quebra do menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vê se isto é o que queres:

```
nav a{
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
}

.img-class
{
 float: left; 
 margin-right: 15px;
}

.collapse
{
    width: 700px;
}

li
{
     float: left;
     margin: 10px; 
}

nav.navbar.navbar-default {
background: transparent;
border: none;
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

div img {

    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;

}

ul.nav.navbar-nav.cl-effect-1 {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
float: none;
display: table;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 110px;
/* width: 80%; */
}

ul.nav.navbar-nav.cl-effect-1 li a {
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Century Gothic;
}

nav a:hover{
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8MY9/2/)

Comment: ainda nao ta alinhado e centralizado ;/

Comment: quando diminui a tela, ele quebra, nao fica na linha

Comment: @Furlan, já editei a minha resposta, vê se é o que queres

Comment: nao cara, ainda continua fora :( ,eu nao to conseguindo

Comment: Meu, tens de te explicar melhor: continua fora? O quê?

Comment: o conteudo esta configurado assim:

width:80%; margin:0 auto;

o menu tem que ficar da mesma forma, entende?

Comment: @Furlan, desculpa mas não tou a entender. Neste [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8MY9/3/) adicionei borders para melhor compreensão: o menu mantém-se dentro do `navbar`, certo? Não tou a ver qual é o problema

Comment: consegui o resultado: [site](http://www.planow.com.br/nobre)

Comment: Continuo sem perceber o que querias mas ainda bem que conseguiste! Boa @Furlan!

Answer (score 0):

Tenta modificar o float:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 133px;
  height: auto;
}
```

O menu ta quebrando por causa da imagem.

E tenta diminuir font-size usando media query.

```
@media (max-width: 778px) {
 .navbar .navbar-nav {
  font-size: 12px;
 }
}
```

Comment: da olha olhada, [site](http://www.planow.com.br/nobre) o lance é o font-size, porem eu não posso aumentar a fonte, precisava aumentar o espaço entre as li sem que ocorra a quebra do menu